# pyudev type object 'Context' has no attribute '_libudev'

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyudev

I am using the [pyudev](https://pyudev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library on `Debian GNU/Linux 8.7 (jessie)` with `python2.7` to detect USB devices as follows:

```
import sys
import pyudev

def main():
    os = canary.helpers.get_platform_system()

    if os.lower() == "linux":
        print("linux")
        context = pyudev.Context

        monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
        monitor.filter_by(device_type='usb')

    elif os.lower() == 'darwin': # actually OS X
        print("OS X is currently not supported, if you would like to add support make a pull request. Aborting...")
        sys.exit()
    elif os.lower() == 'windows':
        print("Windows is currently not supported, if you would like to add support make a pull request. Aborting...")
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print("Unknown operating system. Aborting...")
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As shown in multiple examples - however when I run the code I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/marvin/src/usb_canary/usb_canary.py
linux
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/marvin/src/usb_canary/usb_canary.py", line 45, in <module>
main()
File "/home/marvin/src/usb_canary/usb_canary.py", line 30, in main
monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyudev/monitor.py", line 121, in from_netlink
monitor = context._libudev.udev_monitor_new_from_netlink(
AttributeError: type object 'Context' has no attribute '_libudev'
```

Originally after installing `pyudev` via pip I forgot to ensure I had `libudev-dev` installed so I installed `libudev-dev`, uninstalled `pyudev` and reinstalled it via pip, but the error persists.

I am currently running `libudev-dev` version 215

Can anyone advise why this error may be occurring and how to potentially fix it? I have taken a look through their Github issues but have not found anyone having the same issue I've also take a look at their Read the Docs wiki and still no luck.

Comment: There is no need to re-install the package after installing `libudev-dev`.

Comment: Also, the control flow seems very over-complicated. A simple `if os != "linux": print([message]); sys.exit()` should be enough. The user already knows which system they are on ;)

Comment: I was planning on later branching the script to other operating systems which I assumed I would need different packages to monitor USB devices - but I'm probably over engineering it at the moment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to instantiate the Context to use it, so add parantheses:

```
context = pyudev.Context()
```

Then `filter_by` requires another input argument. But if you look at the docs you could probably figure it out.

Comment: Silly overlook on my behalf. It's now working, thank you!